# Is the following equation about expectation holds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Suppose $E(Z) = 0$ and $\lambda>0$, we consider the following equation,
$$
E\{Z\exp(\lambda Z)\} E\{\exp(2\lambda Z)\} \geq E\{Z\exp(2\lambda Z)\} E\{\exp(\lambda Z)\}.
$$
Will the above equation hold? (This is function related to moment generating function.)

Comment: It would help improve your question and potentially get a more positive response if you explained how this is related to the moment generating function and where you encountered this inequality or why you are interested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the inequality is in general false. Take $Z$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then it is true that $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$, however, if we compute all the expectations

$$
\mathbb{E}[Ze^{\lambda Z}] = \frac{e^{\lambda} - e^{-\lambda}}{2}, \quad \mathbb{E}[Ze^{2\lambda Z}] = \frac{e^{2\lambda} - e^{-2\lambda}}{2} \\
\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda Z}] = \frac{e^{\lambda} + e^{-\lambda}}{2}, \quad \mathbb{E}[e^{2\lambda Z}] = \frac{e^{2\lambda} + e^{-2\lambda}}{2}
$$
we get, simplifying the factor $2$ at denominator

$$
(e^{\lambda} - e^{-\lambda})(e^{2\lambda} + e^{-2\lambda}) \ge (e^{2\lambda} - e^{-2\lambda})(e^{\lambda} + e^{-\lambda})
$$
which holds true only for $\lambda \le 0$, contraddicting the hypothesis.